# Java property file write - escaped characters for http url and encrypted values

Tags: java, encryption, utf-8, properties, iso-8859-1

I have an application property file which I have to read and replace some key's value from a golden property file. I was successful in replacing the value. But as the golden property has the value encrypted like ![Vhrg35hf] when replaced and written in the app property it escapes some characters like `!\[Vhrg35hf\]`. Can you recommend any solution with code? I read some Stack qns for ISO8589 to UTF8 conversion and tried but no luck.

Comment: This has nothing to do with charsets.  What you're seeing is normal and harmless.  See [Properties.load](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-) for details.

Comment: Why? This is defined behaviour. It will be read back correctly. There is no problem here to solve.